# Rayman Legends runs slow in FullScreen mode

Tags: technical-issues, windows-8, rayman-legends

The game runs slow in fullscreen on matter what resolution  (I'd tried the smallest one) but when I check the *Window Mode* option the game seems to be ok no matter what resolution.

Comment: It would help if you supplied information about your system specs here and match them against the minimum system requirements for the game: http://gamesystemrequirements.com/games.php?id=2112

Comment: I don't think it is a requirements problem because of It works propery on Fullscreen mode, but I will add my system spec.

Answer (score 1):

If your computer meets the minimum requirements for the game, some Steam users have suggested trying:

- Disable all in-game U-Play notification via settings and then start your game.

http://steamcommunity.com/app/242550/discussions/0/864979455481714573/

You should also make sure you are running the most recently released drivers for your video card.

Comment: Wow! It looks like my problem. I'll try it when I have the chance.

Answer (score 0):

Making sure my laptop was not running in power saving mode fixed this problem for me:

1. Open Control Panel
2. Go to Hardware & Sound
3. Go to Power Options
4. Select High Performance

If this resolves the problem, you can then adjust your power saving options accordingly.